# Difference between !(n & 1) and n & 1 == 0 in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bitwise-and

For some reason in C++, the expressions `if(!(n & 1))` and `if(n & 1 == 0)` seem to not be equivalent.

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: Try `if((n & 1) == 0)` instead of `if (n & 1 == 0)`.

Answer (score 14):

- `if(!(n & 1))` will evaluate to `true` **if the least significant bit of `n` is `1`**.
- `if(n & 1 == 0)` is equivalent to `if(n & (1 == 0))`, which will become `if (n & 0)`, which is **always `false`**.

Check out the [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), you will see that `==` precedes `&`.

Answer (score 9):

Because of operator precedence. `n & 1 == 0` is parsed as `n & (1 == 0)`, not `(n & 1) == 0`.

Comment: On the subject of operator precedence and brackets, note also that `!(n & 1)` will be different from `!n & 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally (n&1), if we assume n is integer example 2 then first it will convert in 32bit integer so 2= 00000000000000000000000000000010  and in the other hand 1=00000000000000000000000000000001 now we apply "&" operator which return us 0 (you can simply do a Binary Multiplication). Now if we take an example as 3=00000000000000000000000000000011, here output will be 1.

So basically we use n&1 to check the last bit is set or not. (you can also say the number is even or odd)

Now in your question,
1.if(!(n & 1)) : here first n&1 will perform and what ever the value returned it will Logical Not.

2. if(n & 1 == 0) : for this here we need to know that "==" execute first then "&" will execute because of operator precedence. so here (1==0) return a 0 bcz both integers are not equal and then we will do n&0 and we all no if we multiply anything with 0, then it will return 0, so it will return always false.